# Connect GoPro Hero5 Session to raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, gopro

I am doing project using raspberry pi 3 model B. For the video capture I have decided to use GoPro Hero5 Session camera. But now I can not find a way to get the input video from it to raspberry pi. My code is working for other USB cameras. I tried with connection via usb cable.
I am in a serious situation since a had spend lot of money for the GoPro camera.
Can anyone suggest me a way get out of trouble.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please post those question in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind having 1 seconds of delay and low resolution preview? You can use WiFi to stream to the pi. See my examples on GitHub: http://github.com/konradit/goprostream

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what i want is to stream videos from pi to computer using socket. Because pi will not able to process video. So, if gopro connect with wifi. Can i use socket to connect pi with computer??

Comment: can you please tell me what do first to connect gopro and pi via wifi